# Omit sub-directory from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am running my application on apache using XAMMP. I have an api project in my main project folder that resides in the following directory on my machine.

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/api/`

The main index file for the api is in a subfolder under `api/public/index.php`

I have an .htaccess in the public folder that loads my index.php. 
What I want is to access my api with the following url:

`http://localhost/project/api/{api endpoints}` `http://localhost/project/api/public/{api endpoints}` Right now this WORKS

I have tried adding an .htaccess in the api folder and paralell to the api folder with the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/$ api/public [L]
```

I just get object not found without an error logged.

I have tried adding an Alias in my httpd.conf in my apache folder

```
lias /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/academy/api "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/academy/api/public"
```

Same error.

How can I omit `public` from my url and access my index.php in that folder from the api folder. Been on this for hours reading different SO posts and other forums but can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You nearly had it. Put this in your .htaccess in your api folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/api/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

I omitted the [L] flag since it's not necessary and you may want to apply further rewrites later.

Comment: I get 404 page not found with that url

Comment: Did you remove the alias from your main config?

Comment: I also added a condition that is necessary.

Comment: Yes, I did. Not here anymore

Comment: Now, I get [Tue Jan 17 21:41:52.265215 2017] [core:alert] [pid 61678] [client 127.0.0.1:53196] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/academy/api/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '!^/api/public/'

Comment: Sorry, tired here.

Comment: Back to 404 not found

Comment: What are you visiting to get that?

Comment: Are you using a .htaccess file in your api folder or the root? It should be in your api folder but can be modified to go in root.

Comment: Can you confirm where the .htaccess file is?

Comment: Inside the `api` directory

Comment: Please add "LogLevel rewrite:trace3" to your main config and then post the log results after trying to visit that address again.